# What are advantages of passing a scope as method parameter?

Tags: objective-c, methods, parameters, scope

I have recently discovered that it is possible to pass a new scope into method parameters. Eg.:

```
UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[testView addSubview:({
    UIImageView *imView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [imView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]];
    imView;
})];
```

It looks like a very clean way to wrap a code that we don't want to be visible in the current scope, but are there any other advantages or disadvantages of passing parameters this way?

Comment: This isn't passing scope as a parameter; what you are using is a GCC extension called [Statement Exprs](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:xquzOjG3kzsJ:https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) (link is to Google cached page because the GCC site seems to be having issues right now) — this allows you to put multiple statements into one expression, returning the last expression in the statement block. This is a convenience similar to creating an anonymous block which returns `imView` and immediately calling it.

Comment: In any case, this passes nothing but `imView` into `-addSubview:`; you could just as well move the `imView` construction lines to before the `-addSubview:` call. (Unlike actually creating and calling a block which constructs and returns `imView`, which has slightly different memory management semantics.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing into the right direction @ItaiFerber .I understand that Statement Expressions are executed in its own scope, right? So any variables declared in a Statement Expression are hidden in the parent scope?  It looks like a really great way of grouping small parts of code. Do you know about any disadvantages of using them in ObjectiveC?

Comment: Yep, these expressions have their own scope, so they don't reveal any variables into the parent scope. They're convenient for doing object initialization as you are doing here (and much more so even in macros, like `maxint` found in the link above). As for disadvantages, none that I can really think of in practice. In theory, since this is a GCC extension, it's technically not portable, but since Clang implements it, this is mostly a non-issue (this would be more problematic for portable C code).

Comment: It might also be confusing at first to someone who's never seen this feature before, but that only becomes a problem if you're working on a team. **tl;dr:** not really, go ahead and use it if it makes your code more readable